# TableView only showing Part of data read in from Firebase

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, firebase, asynchronous

I have the following code which adds a "Trip" to the Firbase Database

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(user).child("Trips").childByAutoId()

        if Double(distanceText.text!) != nil {
            trip.distance = Double(distanceText.text!)!
        } else {
            print("invaliddouble")
        }
        if tripNameText != nil {
            trip.title = tripNameText.text!
        }

        let tripType = bikeWalkToggle.titleForSegment(at: bikeWalkToggle.selectedSegmentIndex)

        trip.transportType = tripType!
        ref.child("Distance").setValue(trip.distance);ref.child("TripName").setValue(trip.title);ref.child("Transport").setValue(trip.transportType)

        navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)


    }
```

The issue is when I add it the separate database reading operation performed by my TableView in a different UIViewController triggers when the first value of Distance is written.

I have my table view configured to show each line as such

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

        if commuteArray[indexPath.row].isFilled(){
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(commuteArray[indexPath.row].title!) by \(commuteArray[indexPath.row].transportType!) \n Distance: \(String(describing: commuteArray[indexPath.row].distance!)) miles"}
        return cell
    }
```

So what I end up getting is a valid distance shown for the new item but just Default values for Transport Type and Title. Even when the view is reloaded it seems to leave these blank until I close the whole app and reopen it forcing a full reload of the data from the Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be writting all three values for your trip to the database at the same time, using just one call to `setValue`

```
ref.setValue([
  "Distance": trip.distance,
  "TripName": trip.title,
  "Transport": trip.transportType
])
```